# How to find maven dependency that are not used?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

For `IntelliJ` `Maven` project how do I know which dependency in the POM was not used in the Java codes in the project, is there a tool for that?

Comment: try it http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools for that.  For instance you can use the maven dependency plugin (looks like Marco put that in a comment already).

I've used Tattletale in the past: http://www.jboss.org/tattletale/downloads